# Spurious m for unscaled summary values in SEDE home page

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, si-prefix

Now that [SEDE](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) includes some smaller web sites, you can see the smaller amounts show as millions until you hover over them and see the m shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my bad, should be sorted in a few minutes